# click-able div using Jquery(kohana)

Tags: jquery, kohana-3

I am using kohana framework.

I am trying to make div click able and i dont think it will be possible to do it with konaha

```
<?php echo HTML::anchor($link .$test1->getid(). '/travel'); ?>
```

I think my best way will be with jquery `windown.location.href`

My question now is how will I make

```
<?php echo HTML::anchor($link .$test1->getid(). '/travel'); ?>
```

work in jquery?

I know it is normally

```
$(".grip_box").click(function() {
    window.location = ""; // but this is where my problem is. as the url is different depending on the idea `$link.$test->getid`
});
```

I am new to kohana and MVC in general.

```
<div class="general"> //this diiv just keep things in line and make sure that the grid works in the right way.
    <div class"grip_box"> --this is the div I want to make click-able
        <div class"couunt"> // this just shows the number of comment and will take you the comment to save you time from scrolling
         <?php echo HTML::anchor($link . $test1->getId() . '/travel#comments', count ($travelcomment)); ?>
        <?php echo count($countnumber); ?>
        </div>
            <div class="title">
            <?php echo HTML::anchor($link2 . $test1->getId() . '/view', $test1->getTitle()); ?>
            </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: what is the output html of it? post that too.

Comment: i'm not familiar with kohana but if there's a way to set an id for your anchor, that would be the way to acheive this: $("#you_anchor_id").click(function() {...

Comment: @Jai Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @Sarahjames no actually i wanted to see what is the rendered html at runtime in the browser.

Comment: @Jai sorry. The file is quiet long but it basically a foreach loop. The first few lines checks to see if the contain of the page is empty and if it is then show a "sorry this contain is empty" else loop around each contain and render it into a grip(the div I added to the question".

Comment: @Jai the div i added to the question is getting render to the users

Comment: @SarahJames actualy that was a solution for you, if you can set an id for the anchor element

Comment: @FabioG can you put it in an answer. because what you have showed me if incomplete because `$link .$test1->getid()` is missing.

Comment: `<?php echo HTML::anchor($link .$test1->getid(). '/travel'); ?>` need to see what is the output of this `php`?

Comment: @Jai I am trying to make  `DIV click-able` `<?php echo HTML::anchor($link .$test1->getid(). '/travel'); ?>` is just how kohana does the `<a herf=""> </a>`. for example `<?php echo HTML::anchor($link .$test1->getid(). '/travel'); ?>` will be `<a href="www.something.com/test1/21"> </a>`

Comment: @sarahjames `$(".grip_box a").click(function(e) {` won't it work.

Comment: @Jai how will I assign `$link . $idea->getId() . '/view'` to jquery?

Comment: @sarahjames see the answer i just posted, hope this helps.

Comment: @Jai if you look in the `title` class. the url I am trying to redirect to is in that div. is they a way to get jquery get the url from that div and then redirect someone when they click on that div using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple links, all that `HTML::anchor` does is it calls `URL::site` and builds an `a` tag with it.

You can just call that method yourself, like this:

```
...
window.location = "<?php echo URL::site($link . $test1->getid() . '/travel') ?>"
...
```

You will need to put this JavaScript in the page itself and not in an outside JavaScript file, but that's probably OK.

---

**UPDATE:** Here's a cleaner way to do it that I couldn't type in the mobile app last night...

The cleanest way to do this is probably to use `data`-attributes:

HTML

```
<div class="general">
    <div class"grip_box" data-url="<?php echo URL::site($link . $test1->getid() . '/travel') ?>">
        <div class"count">
         <?php echo HTML::anchor($link . $test1->getId() . '/travel#comments', count ($travelcomment)); ?>
        <?php echo count($countnumber); ?>
        </div>
            <div class="title">
            <?php echo HTML::anchor($link2 . $test1->getId() . '/view', $test1->getTitle()); ?>
            </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".grip_box").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-url')) {
        window.location = $(this).attr('data-url');
    }
});
```

This is the most flexible because you can use it for any elements on the page with very little change to the code.

Alternatively, you could store just the id in a `data`-attribute like this:

```
...
<div class"grip_box" data-itemid="<?php echo $test1->getid() ?>">
...
```

and then build the rest in the JavaScript:

```
...
window.location = "BEGINNING_OF_URL" + $(this).attr('data-itemid') + "/travel";
...
```

Comment: Thanks Moshe but I wouldnt use this because I like a js file to be in a js folder dont like mixing it with a php file. But I will use the jquery to get the url in the `title` class.

Comment: @SarahJames see my update.  You shouldn't use the `title` attribute because it's not meant for that.  However, `data`-attributes are specifically designed for this exact purpose.